# Is there a function in networkx algorithm that returns the cliques/clusters/components around certain nodes that I specify?

Tags: nodes, networkx, directed-graph

I'm using networkx in a Telecom CDR data to define the network influencers and their circle of inlfuence. I defined influencers as nodes whose Eigen-Vector Centrality is above a certain threshold, but I still can't define their circle of influence, which is the directly connected nodes to the influencer node with a distance = 1. Do we have a function in networkx that does the same? By the way, my graph is a Directed graph.

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(CDR1, 'A', 'B', ['WEIGHT'], create_using=nx.DiGraph())



df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    DEGREE = dict(G.degree),
    DEGREE_CENTRALITY = nx.degree_centrality(G),
    CLUSTERING = nx.clustering(G),
    EIGENV_CENTRALITY=nx.eigenvector_centrality(G)
    ))




df['Influencer']=np.where(df['EIGENV_CENTRALITY']> 1.022186e-05,1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an undirected graph, this is

```
G.neighbors(node)
```

If it is directed and you want those that are reached from the node, it's again

```
G.neighbors(node)
```

or `G.successors(node)` also works.

If it is directed and you want just those with edges to the node it's

```
G.predecessors(node)
```

Comment: But they will return an iterator, not a list. How do I get a list of users numbers within the influence circle?

Comment: To turn an iterator into a list, simply do `list(G.neighbors(node))`.

Comment: the list returned from G.successors(node) is a list of key iterators. Applying the list() function will not change anything. It will still be a list of key iterators.

Comment: What version of networkx do you have?  For me:  `H=nx.DiGraph()`....   `H.add_edge(1,2)`.... `list(H.successors(1))` gets the output `[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the answer to my question. I used the following lines of code:

```
circle_pre=[]
for inf in influencers_pre.index:
    for n in G_pre.neighbors(inf):
        circle_pre.append(n)
len(circle_pre)
```

where circle_pre is a list of nodes names directly connected to the influencers nodes, which I defined as the circle of influence.